# Linear Combination of Points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, discrete-geometry

I am reading Lecture Notes on Discrete Geometry. It says "The linear span of a set $X$ can be described as the set of all linear combinations of points of $X$." Here $X\in{R^d}$. I am not sure what does it mean by linear combination of points. I only know the concept of linear combination of vectors. I haven't find any useful information by Googling these keywords. Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: When working in $\mathbb R^n$, points and vectors are often conflated.

Comment: @amd Thanks for comment! Yeah, but I am not very sure, because the author also uses the word vector to denote the subtraction of two points.

Comment: Yes, the displacement from one point to another is a vector. Some distinguish between “free” vectors such as these and “fixed” vectors that represent a displacement from some fixed origin (aka “position vector“). It’s the latter that are used interchangeably with “point.” Strictly speaking, these are different objects (it doesn’t make sense to add points, for instance) but in a Euclidean space you can be pretty sloppy about the distinction between them.

Comment: @amd OK, that makes sense. Thanks for sharing:-)

Answer (score 1):

A combination of a finite number of points $P_k$ written under the form :

$$P=\sum_{k=1}^n a_kP_k\tag{1}$$

defines a unique manner point $P$ (called the barycenter of points $P_k$ with weights $a_k$) under the condition that the $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=1\tag{2}$$

Two steps for giving an indisputable meaning to (1).

- first step: refer to the non-ambiguous notation with vectors for a given origin $O$ :

$$\vec{OP}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\vec{OP_k}\tag{3}$$

- second step: as being independent from the choice of origin $O$ (and this is where condition (2) is used) ; indeed, we can transform (3) in the following way :

  $$\color{red}{\vec{OO'}}+\vec{O'P}=\color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\vec{OO'}}+\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\vec{O'P_k}\tag{4}$$

where the colored items, once cancelled, give a relationship analogous to (3), with $O$ replaced by $O'$.

Example :

$$G=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1nP_k\tag{1}$$

is the center of gravity of the system of points $P_k$.

Comment: @user:305862 I understand that your answer shows that linear combinations of vectors are basis-independent. However, according to p. 10 of https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis6100/geombchap2.pdf (Basics of Affine Geometry): "the linear combination of points is frame dependent". As you wrote "Two steps for giving an indisputable meanig to (1)", which refers to points, do you disagree with the reference given here, or am I misunderstanding your answer. Either way, I find the idea of the "frame dependence of linear combinations of points" to be counterintuitive. Can you please clarify? Thank you.

Comment: Jean Marie Apologies for possible multiple copies of comments - I wasn't sure how to write "@Jean Marie" as it wasn't showijng in the added comment.